# Trying to get info from database nodejs / sqlite

Tags: node.js, typescript, sqlite, express, backend

I'm doing a login prototype for my app, on the backend I'm trying to recieve the info (email and password) from the frontend to compare with the registered info from the database and validate the user login.

This is what I have done

```
    const infos = request.query;
    const email = infos.email as string;            // email input frontend
    const password = infos.password as string;      // password input frontend
 
    const checkLogin = await db('usersLoginsDB')    // catching equal from database
    .where('usersLoginsDB.email', '=', email)      
    .where('usersLoginsDB.password', '=', password)
    .select('usersLoginsDB.email', 'email')             
    .select('usersLoginsDB.password', 'password')
```

After this, I have a checkLogin as type any[] with email and password, and I can't do something like checkLogin.email to use this info.

I tried this and kind of worked

```
    let resultEmail = checkLogin.map(a => a.email) as unknown;
    let testEmail = resultEmail as string;
```

But I'm not sure this is right, I would like to know if there is another way to do it, to get this checkLogin.email to work, or to get the email info from the database in a different way other than using .where and .select.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is your `db`? does it have type for queries?

Answer (score 0):

Probably checkout [knex](http://knexjs.org/) or any other query builder. You don’t need to query everything all at once. You can do this in simple steps:

1. Query dB to check if the user email exists if it doesn’t throw an error.
2. If user email exists you need to now verify password. Query the DB to verify it.
3. If all goes well you can sign in the user. For example, if you have JWT setup send the token back to the user.